# Creating a service fabric instance listener without startup.cs (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I am writing a service fabric project in .NET 6, and I've consolidated the `startup.cs` code into `program.cs`. I have created a `CreateServiceInstanceListeners` method for setting up listeners.

However, the code that I originally took from `startup.cs`, and thus there's a `UseStartup<Startup>()` line added. I was wondering what the substitute for that should be if I'm not using `startup.cs`, and instead everything related to service startup is now in `program.cs`.

Comment: Does your Program.cs file start with / contain `var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`? Or do you use the older style?

Comment: Yes, it starts with that! I switched from the older style to the newer one.

Comment: dose your codes contain something like : KestrelCommunicationListener(ServiceContext serviceContext, string endpointName, Func<string, AspNetCoreCommunicationListener, IWebHost> build) which require IWebHost? you may try  regist services/create middleware pipeline with Configure/Configure Services method without Startup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the call for `UseStartup<Startup>` any longer as you moved all your code into your Program.cs file.

You still have the two sections for `ConfigureServices` and `Configure` (but not the methods). In the default template for the Program.cs file they start with corresponding comments.

First you configure the services for your dependency injection container and after the call to `builder.Build()` you configure the request pipeline (the code that was in the `Startup.Configure` method before.